# Which one of $n!$ or $e^{n^2}$ grows faster?

Tags: calculus

I would expect $n!$ to grow faster because factorial growth is generally faster than exponential growth, but wolfram alpha says that $\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{x!}{e^{x^2}}\right)=0$, so I would appreciate if anyone can explain why this occurs.

Comment: Use Stirling's approximation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While $e^{x^2}$ *uses* an exponential, it's a function that grows (much) faster than exponentially. In fact, you can show your limit without needing to know any details of the asymptotics of the factorial; it's almost trivially the case that $n!\lt n^n$. But by taking logs, we see that $n!\lt 
n^n = e^{n\ln n} \lt e^{n^2}$.

Comment: Thank you, this solution is simple to understand but makes the answer very clear.

Answer (score 2):

Famously $\ln n!\sim n\ln n\in o(n^2)$, so $n!\in o(\exp n^2)$. [Indeed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Derivation),$$\ln n!=\sum_{k=1}^n\ln k\sim\int_1^n\ln kdk=n\ln n-n\sim n\ln n.$$

Answer (score 2):

A fancy way to do it: let $\;a_n:=\cfrac{n!}{e^{n^2}}\;$ , then

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(n+1)!}{e^{(n+1)^2}}\cdot\frac{e^{n^2}}{n!}=\frac{n+1}{e^{2n+1}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$

since exponential grows way faster than polynomial.

Thus, by the ratio (D'Alembert) test, the series $\;\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\cfrac{n!}{e^{n^2}}\;$ converges, which means

$$\frac{n!}{e^{n^2}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\implies n!<e^{n^2}\;\;\text{for all large enough}\;\;n$$

Comment: Yeah, that infinite series is where I originally saw this limit as I incorrectly used the limit test on that problem.

Answer (score 2):

$$e^{n^2}=(e^n)^n\gg n^n\gg n!$$

E.g. $$e^{10^2}=2.688117\cdots 10^{43}\gg 10!=3628800.$$